# How to make square divs shrink instead of hide when resizing screen?

Tags: css

[image: No descrription]I have a collection of a couple of divs (called buttons) inside a div container.

When attempting to resize the screen to check for responsiveness, (trying to keep them centered in the middle of the screen) instead of shrinking, the buttons FIRST get clipped from (or hide behind) both sides of the screen.

here is my code:

```
.button {
    outline: 1px solid black;

    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;

    flex: 1 0 1rem;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.parentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Below are the global styles:

```
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
      Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

The html is made using components:

```
<div className={parentContainer}>
    <div className={container}>
        <HeaderButton />
        <HeaderButton />
        <HeaderButton />
        <HeaderButton />
        <HeaderButton />
        <HeaderButton />
    </div>
</div>
```

The header button component:

```
const Button = () => {
    return (
        <div className={button}>
            <h1>{props.text}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

Any idea how I might achieve what I'm aiming for?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you add the html as well ?

Comment: Yes of course, one sec.

Comment: Ok, it's added! @yousoumar

Comment: Have you considered giving the buttons a fixed aspect-ratio? (1 / 1 for a square)

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably due to the buttons having fixed width.

I'd suggest adding a responsive variant for the `.container`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .container {
       flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

This will make the buttons fall one below the other.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but that doesn't have the behavior that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex for responsiveness and percentages for element widths:

```css
body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.d1,.d2,.d3,.d4,.d5{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <div class="d2"></div>
        <div class="d3"></div>
        <div class="d4"></div>
        <div class="d5"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I attempted something similar. What seems to be occurring in the solution you provided, is that the square actually becomes a rectangle and upon shrinking the screen the width and height sizes are independent of one another. It starts off as a horizontal rectangle then morphs into a vertical rectangle.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. If you want it to be responsive simplier way, I think this is the right one. At least I use this one a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please use flex-wrap: wrap

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first I'd like to thank everyone for their responses, but the solution that I needed was in fact `aspect-ratio`:

```
.button {
width: 80%;
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

margin-top: 5%;
width: 90vw;

gap: 3.5%;

}
```